# Eliminar con condición en JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy trabajando en un código sobre alquiler de vestidos y me pide eliminar clientes siempre y cuando no tenga alquileres, he tratado de hacerlo pero el codigo que tengo elimina tenga o no alquileres (el proyecto es en Lista múltiple enlace). Agradeceria mucho si me ayudan a corregir esto, el código de eliminar clientes es el siguiente (el codigo es mas extenso pero trato de poner lo necesario ya que no puedo poner todo el codigo:

```
public boolean Eliminar(int n){
    NodoCliente aux, ant;
    ant = null;
    aux = pri;
    
    while(aux != null && aux.getCedula() != n){
        ant = aux;
        aux = aux.sigCli;
    }
    
    if(aux == null){
        return false;
    }else if(aux == pri){
        pri = pri.sigCli;
        aux.sigCli = null;
    }else if(aux == ult){
        ult = ant;
        ult.sigCli = null;
    }else{
        ant.sigCli = aux.sigCli;
        aux.sigCli = null;
    }
    return true;
}
```

El código de alquilar vestidos es el siguiente:

```
public boolean AlquilarVestido(int xcedula, String xTipo, int xPrecio){
    NodoCliente aux = pri;
    while(aux != null && xcedula != aux.getCedula()){
        aux = aux.sigCli;
    }
    if(aux == null){
        return false;
    }else{
        NodoVestido nVestido = new NodoVestido(xTipo, xPrecio);
        if(aux.sigVes == null){
            aux.sigVes = nVestido;
        }else{
            NodoVestido aux1 = aux.sigVes;
            while(aux1.sigVes != null){
                aux1 = aux1.sigVes;
            }
            aux1.sigVes = nVestido;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Y los alquileres dónde están??

Comment: @Yussef ya actualice la pregunta con el código de alquilar vestido

Comment: Esa cantidad de if anidados la veo poco efectiva, ¿Por qué no usas un switch de aux?

Comment: Está raro porque al NodoCliente.sigVes le asignas el NodoVestido que creas... seguro???

Comment: No estoy entiendo. Pero supongo que tienes una lista de clientes, y en cada cliente tienes una lista de alquileres. Es asi?